# Are biscuit wrappers (the shiny looking ones) recyclable ? Can I dump them in regular dry waste collecting containers?

Tags: recycling, plastic, dry-waste, waste-segregation

Recurring waste has been a recurring theme in my questions about waste management. Want to ensure recyclability or reduce waste in everyday use.

Are these biscuit wrappers recyclable ?

A neighbourhood school has been having a environ-care project for children, urging them to collect wrappers. However, it now looks like the local scrap shop dealer does not know whether they are really recyclable or whether these are destined to the landfill anyway, whether or nor seggregated. Some articles on the Internet seem to mention that, these are not recyclable, is it true ?

If it helps in context: This is in a small town in India, options for responsible disposal are limited. Only the local scrapdealer, even that with limited knowledge of overall impact or options.

http://bengaluru.citizenmatters.in/1582-reduce-reuse-recyle-waste-1582

Of course, they are best avoided. But setting that aside, are they recyclable and whether they can be dumped with other plastic such as polythene covers.

[image: A Good Day Biscuit packet]

[image: Good Day Biscuit Cover, when opened]

When unfolded : (washed and dried) :

[image: Good Day Biscuit Cover, inner, unfolded]

Comment: I think [my answer](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/a/6114/99) to your 'blister pack' question also answers this question because the biscuit wrapper you posted is also a combination of plastic and aluminium. Again there is a recycler that accepts biscuit wrappers (the Terracycle company I mentioned before even has [a special program for it in the UK](http://www.terracycle.co.uk/en-UK/brigades/22)), but there seem to be very few other recyclers, so the chance of one being near you is slim. Are you okay with closing this question as a duplicate of your other question?

Comment: Okay, voted to close the question. Didn't know they are of the same type.

Comment: I'd say this could be a standalone question. In Australia, the RedCycle program recycles soft plastics, including the one depicted here, but does not include blister packs in their lists of accepted items.